# Getting the error "from robot import run_cli ImportError: No module named robot" even when robotframework was installed in the system using python?

Tags: python, robotframework

While running the command `pybot --version`
I'm getting the error

> from robot import run_cli ImportError: No module named robot

I have already installed robotframework 3.0 with python after downloading the module with its setup.py file.

I tried installing and reinstalling it multiple times.

Also I have verified the environment variables for the same which also seems to be inline with what I have installed.

I checked in the site-packages also where I am able to see robotframework 3.0 present in them.

I checked in the `/usr/local/bin` as well as `/home/.local/bin` folder I can see both robot and pybot available. But for running the command `robot --version` also it is showing the same error.

I really don't know what is missing.

My Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- python 2.76
- robotframework 3.0

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is not really a solution to your problem, but is there any specific reason for you to be using the 3.0 version? There is a newer one available - https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/tree/v3.1.1

Comment: Hi Kacper,
                I feel the upgrade to new version might not solve the problem as I had this setup running perfectly in my other system.. I recently changed my laptop where I was doing all these setups freshly..

Comment: it's possible that you installed it for one specific version of python, but when you run pybot it's using a different version of python.

Comment: And to check on that ^, run these commands - `which python`, and `which pip` - they should be a part of the same install; then having the full path to "pip", run `/path/to/pip list` - is the library there?

Comment: I had a check with the above mentioned commands the robot library and pybot are present at both the places.. 

@BryanOakley I made a check.. I have 2 pythons in my system that is version 2.7.6 and 3.. By default my system is picking up 2.7.6 which is inline with my current python version..

Can you/someone provide more granuality on this problem..?

Comment: Since the `pybot` command has been deprecated in the latest versions of robot, perhaps you should try upgrading and using the `robot` command instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please see my reply to kacper's comment on comment number 2.. I am mentioning about this setup working fine previously.. Also I have another windows system where this is working absolutely fine.. Bye the way I am getting a similar error for robot --version as well

Comment: @BryanOakley You have any comments or suggestions to provide?

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience on installing the ROBOT Framework in linux machine. But just check whether you have done the following:

1. How did you install ROBOT Framework? Is it by pip command or with the downloaded source file? Have you tried with pip command if any?
2. Set python path in your environment path/variables. Example in windows, C:\Python27\
3. Set python scripts folder in your environment path/variables. Example in windows C:\Python27\Scripts

Last, maybe you can share the output of your 'pip list' command? So, just want to see what are the modules/packages that you have installed.