# How can we run Robot Framework files and Test cases using command line?

Tags: command-line, robotframework

[image: Test Case Hierarchy]

Please can anyone suggest and help how can we execute the Robot Framework Test Cases and Files via command line ?

My Robot Framework Directory Location is as follows : 
**/Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/Robot Files/Charcoal PreProd**

I've tried :

```
robot -L debug Charcoal preprod.robot
```

and got error as :

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in <module>
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'
```

I'am using [ride.py](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/) to create my test cases and the test cases are running fine when i'm using RIDE UI. But I want to run my test cases using ***Robot CLI***. Whenever I'am executing my ***.robot*** file using robot command I'am getting following error

***robot Login.robot 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in 
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'***

Thank You

Comment: Without having your file/folder structure plus the intended use, answering this question is like searching a needle from the haystack. You could just make a generic call `robot <parent_folder>` to run everything, though. The official documentation: [how to run robot test cases](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-test-cases)

Comment: I tried to run mt project directory **Charcoal Preprod** using : 
```robot -L debug Charcoal preprod.robot```
got error as : ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in <module>
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'.```

Comment: i see that you are making use of eclipse, which env is it configured to run on? i mean what is the virtualenv/interpreter is it configured to run on?

Comment: no I'm not making use of eclipse, the screenshot is of Robot Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have robot framework installed and it is found in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

For executing the tests, there are many ways to do this.

Option #1:
Go to `Charcoal PreProd` folder and just `robot Suites`

Option #2:
Go to `Suites` folder and just `robot .`

Option #3:
If you wanna run only `Login` test suite, in `Charcoal PreProd` folder: `robot Login.robot` (assuming the file extension for `Login` file is robot).

Also note that the last argument cannot have spaces as you have in `Charcoal preprod.robot`. In this case, you should use quotes: `'Charcoal preprod.robot'`.

Comment: I'am using [ride.py](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/) to create my test cases and the test cases are running fine when i'm using RIDE UI. But I want to run my test cases using ***Robot CLI***. Whenever I'am executing my ***.robot*** file using robot command I'am getting following error

***robot Login.robot 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in <module>
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'***

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the below error is , you need to go to the same virtualenv/interpreter where you have installed robotframework,as you have configured your eclipse to run on. Otherwise, you will get the below error.

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in <module>
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'
```

**Steps to remedy**

1. You need to use the same virtualenv/interpreter and
2. then make sure you have robotframework installed and
3. then you need to invoke robot, only then it is going to work.

**APPROACH#0**

Assuming that you have created a virtualenv/interpreter with robotframework installed successfully, then you need to just

1. cd to that specific directory and
2. then execute robot as mentioned below.

If you want to run all the testcases from all the files and folders under Prepod

```
cd /Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/Robot\ Files/Charcoal\ PreProd
robot *.robot
```

> **NOTE**: few users are confused regarding "cd" when dir name contains
>   space i have created a simple folder name "sample sd"(there is a space
>   in the folder name)

On mac this works,

```
cd sample\ sd/
06:30 PM##~/sample sd::>
```

Comment: Based on the path, I assume the user is using Windows rather Linux (`Users` versus `home`), so that `cd /Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/Robot Files/Charcoal\ PreProd` might not work as expected. Also depends on which terminal the user is using (cmd.exe, Git Bash, etc.)

Comment: since, the person has not provided which OS he is working on , i have not assumed on anything, the answer is ,irrespective of the os, the approach remains the same.

Comment: On the other hand, the `ModuleNotFoundError` shows a Unix-like path...

Comment: the OS used is IOS

Comment: When i'm giving the entire path in terminal - ***/Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/Robot\ Files/Charcoal\ PreProd/Suites/Login.robot*** it giving ***permission denied***
real problem is I'am using [ride.py](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/) to create and run TC using RIDE UI. But I want to run my test cases using ***Robot CLI***. When I'am executing ***.robot*** file using command I'm getting error - 

***robot Login.robot
  File "/usr/local/bin/robot", line 6, in <module>
    from robot.run import run_cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'***

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540608/getting-the-error-from-robot-import-run-cli-importerror-no-module-named-robot

Comment: yes i did now, it states all related to two different versions of python, I just have python 2.7 installed

Comment: ok , in that case, you need to check whether you have instaleld RF in that python install first. is RF installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203949/discussion-between-tanya-grover-and-forkdbloke).

Answer (score 0):

Setting default python version to 3.6 worked for me